# Como definir a senha para administração do PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, administração-postgresql

Instalei o PostgreSQL no meu Ubuntu usando "apt-get". Andei usando "sudo" para realizar operações (na verdade seguindo um tutorial), mas agora quero administrar o SGBD com um cliente que me pede a senha do usuário administrador "postgres".

Como eu defino esta senha?

Answer (score 8):

Para alterar a senha do usuário postgres, digite o comando:

```
$ sudo passwd postgres
```

Após executar o comando aparecerão as seguintes mensagens:

```
Digite a nova senha UNIX: 
Redigite a nova senha UNIX:
```

Digite a sua senha e redigite a mesma em seguida. Feito isso, iremos logar com o usuário postgres.

```
$ su postgres
```

A senha que será exigida é a mesma que acabamos de alterar.

Agora vamos alterar a senha para conectar ao banco.

Este comando é para a versão 7 ou superior:

```
$ psql -c "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'nova_senha'" -d template1
```

Onde `nova_senha` será a senha que você deseja.

Fonte: [vivaolinux](http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/).

Comment: Uma resposta só com o link é má prática aqui. Se esse link desaparecer um dia, então esta resposta é lixo. Se melhorar a resposta com bom conteúdo eu voto +1

Comment: Opa, nem havia pensado nisso. Me desculpa, vou editar a resposta. Achei que seria errado copiar o conteudo de outro site.

Comment: Pode copiar o conteudo se referir de onde copiou.

Comment: Editado, obrigado pela compreensão não havia pensado nessa possibilidade.

Comment: Se possível @fymoribe coloque as partes de comando dentro de tags: `` para dar destaque ao comando, ex: `$ su postgres`

Comment: Alterado @iTSangar

Answer (score 6):

Acesse o banco de administração do Postgres com esse comando:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

Defina a senha do usuário administrador usando:

```
\password postgres
```

Após digitar e confirmar a senha use o atalho "Crtl+D" para finalizar a administração do banco.

Comment: +1 por evitar o `ALTER USER`, que deixa a nova senha explícita na tela, no `~/.psql_history` do usuário e na log do PostgreSQL caso haja um erro de sintaxe ou o parâmetro de configuração `log_statement` esteja configurado para `ddl` ou `all`.